Linphone showing no text since Xubuntu upgrade to 24.04
I have for the past two years successfully used Linphone desktop (most recently Linphone-5.2.6.AppImage) under Xubuntu 22.04 on my rather elderly laptop.  After recently upgrading to Xubuntu 24.04.1, I found that, while I can still run Linphone and select the various menu items, no text is displayed in Linphone's various screen windows, so the application is essentially unusable.  Other applications still seem to work normally.
Looking at the end of 'linphone1.log' shows many entries similar to those that are listed below:
2024-09-29 15:17:57:304 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: shader compilation failed: "error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups (5/4)\n"
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShader::link: error: Exceeded max nr indirect texture lookups (5/4)
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(matrix): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(textureScale): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(color): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(alphaMin): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(alphaMax): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:17:57:308 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(fontScale): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:17:57:309 [AppRun.wrapped/qt] WARNING QT: :0: QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(vecDelta): shader program is not linked
2024-09-29 15:18:03:717 [AppRun.wrapped/belle-sip] MESSAGE channel [0x64dbb293aab0]: keep alive sent to [UDP://localphone.com:5060]


Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1511655/124466

Thanks for your contribution Archisman.  I tried the suggestion in the link that you provided but it didn't solve my problem.  In fact the problem is not just restricted to the Appimage version of Linphone, it also affects the version (5.0.2-4build5) from the Ubuntu respository installed by 'sudo apt install linphone-desktop'.I have also now observed the same problem in Jami, a deb/ubuntu 24.04 (non-Appimage) version downloaded from jami.net.  The problem appears to be connected with Qt, not Appimage.
